# jquery datepicker not showing calender

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've multiple date pickers on multiple pages.
I am rendering them through partial views.

The issue is that some of them are showing calendar to pick the date and some not.

This is my input tag(raw)

```
<input  name="dtpicker" class="datepicker form-control" id="datepicker">
```

This is my Input tag after adding datepicker

```
<input name="dtpicker" class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="datepicker">
```

I have added my script at the end of partial view as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(this).change();
        },
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            if ($(input).attr('readonly') !== undefined) {
                if (inst.o_dpDiv === undefined)
                    inst.o_dpDiv = inst.dpDiv;
                inst.dpDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>');
            } else {
                if (inst.o_dpDiv !== undefined) {
                    inst.dpDiv = inst.o_dpDiv;
                }
            }
        }
    }).datepicker();
});
```

I noticed one thing that when calendar is not opening

ui-datepicker class has display none property

```
.ui-datepicker{
    width: 17em;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    display: none;
}
```

also no effect on ui-datepicker-div

Can someone help?

Comment: which date picker plugin u r using and what is error come on console

Comment: since you're using partial view, did you check in ur page, is there any other input with the same ID? You cant have multiple elements with the same ID in a html page.

Comment: `$(".datepicker").datepicker();` and try activating your datepicker using class selector instead of id selector

Comment: @jeevanswamy21: I am using jQueryui datepicker

Comment: @SudarpoChong: I do not have any other dom element with the same ID and I've tried doing with class as well but not getting result

Comment: I cant repro ur issue... https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/1warxqy9/

Comment: If i set all ID to be the same, and use the method to activate datepicker, calendar is only open on the first input.. see here https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/1warxqy9/1/

Comment: I am having multiple partial views in one HTML, and datepicker is in those partial views. I think the issue is when I am rendering UI from the partial view. I tried adding it to main view and its working fine but unfortunately, I need to render it from partial view only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160166/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-sudarpo-chong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. My bad. I was loading the jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js file again in partial view which was causing this issue.

Just removed that and its working fine now.